# What would be the best way to migrate work items from TFS 2010 to JIRA?

Tags: tfs, jira

I am in the process of evaluating JIRA as a replacement to TFS 2010.
I know that JIRA has the capability to import from CSV but cannot figure out how to export fields like the History fields from TFS to a spreadsheet.

Any recommendations / tools would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to do what you want.

I am thinking you would need to make your own tool using the TFS API.  I don't know if JIRA has an API to do the inserting, but TFS's api is fairly good.  You could easily get that data out.

For "How To" on the TFS API I usually look to [Shai Raitan's TFS API blog posts](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/tags/TFS+API/default.aspx).

Comment: The link for the TFS API is no longer working

Answer (score 2):

I do custom migrations from all sorts of databases (ClearQuest, TeamTrack, Remedy) into JIRA. It takes about a week to do the job so it isn't cheap but if you have a lot of data and want more information than the standard importers provide, it's one way to go. The CSV importer probably won't do what you want.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Appfire's Enterprise Migration Utility](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugins/com.appfire.jira.plugins.appfire-enterprise-migration-utility). It migrates TFS to JIRA, amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough, create a Query that has all your work items, click on the icon to open in Excel, 
Save the Excel file as CSV. 
done.

Comment: I assume this method would not migrate history or related items, or almost any data that isn't included in the Excel file. So it's certainly doable to import, but really limits what can be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me (sorry about the formatting; it was a .docx):
For every TFS Server:

Create a query by using Iteration Path for all Product Backlog Items and Bugs for every Product and/or every Scrum Team.

A single query can be used for all projects/products by altering the iteration path(s)

Format the results in TFS by selecting the appropriate columns.

Save the query, run it, and open it in Excel an .xlsx file with the word RAW included (for example, XXXX_ALL_WIs_RAW.xlsx).

Using the same file, select Save As… to create and save an excel .csv file.

Note that not all columns/mappings will be used on all projects. Delete unnecessary columns, and change column headings as needed.

The TFS columns/fields, and the Jira fields (some custom) to which they are mapped, for me were:

Iteration Path maps to Scrum Team

ID maps to Legacy ID

Work Item Type maps to Issue Type

Title maps to Summary

Description maps to Description

Acceptance Criteria maps to Acceptance Criteria

Assigned To maps to Assignee (Users must exist in Jira for this to work!)

SubCategory maps to Component/s

Effort maps to Story Points

Severity maps to Priority

Case Number maps to Case ID

Client Name maps to Customer

Platform maps to Environment

Once the .csv has been modified, use File/Check for Issues/Inspect document to determine if modification are required so the inspection results yield no issues.

Save the clean .csv as _CLEAN (for example, XXXX_ALL_WIs_CLEAN.csv).

Rename spreadsheet headers for import to appropriate Jira field names.

Field modifications:

If the work item Acceptance Criteria field has nothing in it, enter “No Acceptance Criteria in the original TFS work item” on the csv.

If the work item Description field has nothing in it, enter “No Description in the original TFS work item” on the csv.

Bugs – Severity must be converted to a number (1 through 5).

Change column headings on the .csv to match the Jira field names, as defined above in 2d.

Clean/Inspect the .csv

If necessary, increase the advanced setting jira.bulk.create.max.issues.per.import in Jira appropriately to handle the number of items being imported (there is a 250 item import limit by default).

In Jira, at the Site Admin Level – Create new Jira projects based on individual products (NOT projects!)

Create or add users that will be used in the various projects.

In Jira, at the Site Admin level – Create Custom Fields as needed

Associate new and existing custom fields to appropriate project screens, and update.

In Jira, at the Site Admin Level – Re-index DB

At the Project level – Create components for the product by using subcategory from TFS. (Can be assigned to Component Lead)

You should now be ready for import into Jira.

Test Case Migration from TFS to Jira/Zephyr if you need it:

Test case migration is a 2-part process. 
The first part will get the test cases from TFS, and create and format an Excel spreadsheet containing the data that will then be imported into Jira (Zephyr). 
The second part of the process will use a Java tool to import the data from the spreadsheet created in Part 1 of the process.

Part 1 – Test Case Export

1. Install TCExport (Used to create the Excel spreadsheet that will be used to import the test cases into Zephyr).
2. When mapping fields while using the .jar tool, use the Excel column letter.

Part 2 – Test Case Import
1.  Download the import utility zfj-importer-utility-0.38.jar

2. This utility can be run by double-clicking the file in most environments. To launch the utility double-click the .jar file or run through the command prompt as: java -jar .
3. Detailed instructions for using the utility can be found here: https://www.getzephyr.com/insights/getting-started-zephyr-jira-importer-utility

Comment: No comments, no issue history though